# Solving an equation with the form $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{array}{l}
 \left( \begin{array}{l}
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2 & 3 &  \cdots  & n  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   2 & 3 & 4 &  \cdots  & {n + 1}  \\
\end{array} \\ 
  \ldots  \ldots  \ldots  \ldots  \ldots  \ldots  \ldots  \ldots  \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   n & n+1 & n+2 &  \cdots  & {2n - 1}  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x_1}}  \\
   {{x_2}}  \\
    \vdots   \\
   {{x_n}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{b_1}}  \\
   {{b_2}}  \\
    \vdots   \\
   {{b_n}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) \\ 
 \left( \begin{array}{l}
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2 & 3 &  \cdots  & n  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 1 & 1 &  \cdots  & 1  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \cdots  &  \vdots   \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 1 & 1 &  \cdots  & 1  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x_1}}  \\
   {{x_2}}  \\
    \vdots   \\
   {{x_n}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{b_1}}  \\
   {{b_2} - {b_1}}  \\
    \vdots   \\
   {{b_n} - {b_{n - 1}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}$$

I started reducing the matrix; 
Am I on the right path? How should I continue?

### EDIT:

current state is:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{l}
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2 & 3 &  \cdots  & n  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 1 & 1 &  \cdots  & 1  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \cdots  &  \vdots   \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   0 & 0 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x_1}}  \\
   {{x_2}}  \\
    \vdots   \\
   {{x_n}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{b_1}}  \\
   {{b_2} - {b_1}}  \\
   \begin{array}{l}
 {b_3} - 2{b_2} + {b_1} \\ 
  \vdots  \\ 
 \end{array}  \\
   {{b_n} - 2{b_{n - 1}} + {b_{n - 2}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$

Comment: Yes, you then can make all rows except first and second rows are zero

Comment: Are the bottom-left entries $2,3$ wrong?

Comment: @pppqqq, thanks. it's a typo

Comment: @Jlamprong, Thanks, but then I get stuck with $n-2$ zero rows with the form of $0...0=b_n-2b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$. How to treat them?

Comment: If $b_{k+2}-2b_{k+1}+b_k \ne 0$ for any $k \ge 1$, then the system has no solutions. Otherwise, you get $n-2$ equations of the form $0_{1 \times n} x = 0$, which are always true and can be discarded, so your system is reduced to the one defined by the first two rows of $A$ and $b$ (2 equations, $n$ unknowns).